# Why does a field's value get erased after a button click in ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net

I need a field to store some information after one asp button click for another asp button's click.

I saw that it wasn't working so I wrote the following simple page codebehind (thinking that perhaps some of my code was causing it) but here I can see that the field really does get re-initialized.

I suppose that every button click reloads the page. Is this true? And if so - how can this be overcome without a static variable (-because what if more than one person is accessing the same page at once...)?

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string s = "a";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        s = "b";
    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        here.InnerText = s;// "here" is an id.
        //returns "a" despite Button1 having been clicked before.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add in your code (EnableViewState)

Comment: Thanks. I tried looking it up but it seems to be referring to controls. How do i do it for a simple variable / field?

Comment: ViewState["Key"] = your value;

Answer (score 2):

Each time you request (get or post) a page, a new instance of the `_Default` class (derived `System.Web.UI.Page`) is created (and then destroyed), the same happens with the contained controls.

See the [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).

> When an ASP.NET page runs, the page goes through a life cycle in which
>   it performs a series of processing steps. These include
>   initialization, instantiating controls, restoring and maintaining
>   state, running event handler code, and rendering. It is important for
>   you to understand the page life cycle so that you can write code at
>   the appropriate life-cycle stage for the effect you intend.

You can persist a value (in your case the value of the field `s`) with different techniques (cookie, session, cache, viewstate, ...), see also [ASP.NET State Management Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s.aspx).